# WordPress static home page with query variables switches template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a static WordPress home page set to use the template defined by front-page.php. I'm defining variables in my functions file like this:

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
  $aVars[] = "ch_businesstype"; // represents the name of the product category as shown in the URL
  $aVars[] = "ch_search";
  return $aVars;
}
```

The home page loads using front-page.php. Though when I load the page with variables - for instance, homepage.com?ch_businesstype=something, the index template is displaying. Why is WordPress switching templates here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems to be something about this function, add_query_vars, that doesn't work on the home page, because if I change my request to homepage.com?sab_businesstype=something, without changing functions.php, the correct template displays, though $_REQUEST doesn't have the data.

Comment: How about if you use "public function" instead of just "function"?